# How to redirect STDOUT and STDERR in Ruby and make them equal?

Tags: ruby, redirect, stdout, stderr

When I call a command in Ruby with `%x{command}`, standard output is captured, and standard error shows on the screen. However I would like both to be captured and I want to watch both on the screen too. How can I achieve this?

```
%x{command 2>&1 1>&2}
```

construction seems to be not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
2.1.3 :005 > %x{(ls -d /boot 2>&1) | tee /dev/stderr}
/boot
 => "/boot\n" 

2.1.3 :006 > %x{(ls /no_such_file 2>&1) | tee /dev/stderr}
ls: cannot access /no_such_file: No such file or directory
 => "ls: cannot access /no_such_file: No such file or directory\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your redirection is all wrong.

`2>&1` Here you are redirecting `stderr` to `stdout`

`1>&2` Here you are redirecting `stdout` back to `stderr`

This is what you want:

`%x{command 2>&1}`

Be sure to call `puts` to get the output to the screen from a script. (since everything is going to stdout now instead of stderr)

`puts %x{command 2>&1}`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx, but in this way both the original stderr and stdout will be captured, and don't appear (real time) on the screen.

Comment: what do you mean don't appear on the screen.

Comment: you need to call `puts` to get output to the screen from a script. the only reason stderr was going to the screen is because it's an error. Updating the answer with `puts`

Comment: status messages are also going to stderr, not only errors and I would like to see them real time, as soon as they are writed to stderr as I called the command with method "system", no capturing.

Comment: `system` is different than `%x{}` or ``. you also can't save the output of `system` to a variable. you may want to take a look at `Open3#popen`

Comment: I just want to merge stdout and stderr to one stream and then make stdout and stderr both would be the merged stream.